# Convert unicode character in Titanium mobile app

Tags: javascript, unicode, titanium

I'm calling api calls to google maps, which returns in json, like below:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?output=json&q=norreport,%20copenhagen

As you can see Nørreport has ø in it - this works good when calling it through the browser, but calling via the titanium app, the unicode equivalent is returned: N\U00f6rreport

How can I convert the \U00f6 into the unicode character? Bearing in mind this in in a Titanium mobile app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't included the text correctly, I was using:

```
json.Placemark[0].AddressDetails.AddressLine
```

When it should be:

```
json.Placemark[0].AddressDetails.AddressLine[0]
```

Conversion is then automatic.